# How to add Job in Customer table with qodbc insert statement

Tags: quickbooks, qodbc

I am trying to add a job to the QuickBooks Customer table using the following sql statement.  The customer table has several CustomFields (columns).  When I apply the statement without the customField/column  the statment works.  When I run the sql line with the customField/column - I get an error and the row IS inserted without the customField/column data

```
INSERT INTO Customer (Name, ParentRefFullName, Companyname, Billaddressaddr1, CustomFieldAddNumber) VALUES ('.10~Root Name 01',  '.00~Root Name 01', 'Zen Enterprise', 'my Address one', '.10' )
```

Error: only with 'CustomFieldAddNumber' set to '.10'
[image]

What is the correct way to add a Job to Customer table with CustomFeilds/Columns ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you download & install QODBC latest version 320 from below link & test again:
http://www.qodbc.com/qodbcDownload.htm

If you are still facing the issue, I kindly request you to please raise a support ticket to the QODBC Technical Support department from below mentioned link & provide requested information:

http://support.flexquarters.com/esupport/index.php?/Tickets/Submit

We may need the following information, I kindly request you to attach below listed files when replying to the ticket.

1) Screenshot of QODBC Setup Screen -- > About

2) Screenshot of the issue you’re facing.

Share Entire Log Files as an attachment in text format from

3) QODBC Setup Screen -- > Messages -- > Review QODBC Messages

4) QODBC Setup Screen -- > Messages -- > Review SDK Messages